# Error while disabling csrutil on macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina, recovery, ntfs, sip

I've tried to disable `csrutil` on Catalina by booting and repeatedly hitting EDIT: `cmd+R`. I've run the terminal and disabled `csrutil`.
I get the error "failed to modify system integrity configuration". This tool needs to be executed from the recovery OS.
[image: recovery os mode]
I am in that mode. What am I doing wrong and how can I disable it?

I need to disable it for installing an [Auto-mount NTFS volumes in read-write mode](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G).

Thank you.

Comment: You probably should have stated you have installed Catalina on an unsupported Mac. (Or maybe a PC instead of a Mac?) I make this assumption based on the image you have posted. This image appears to be the same (except for the language) as [this image](https://i.imgur.com/3R61znG.jpeg), which taken from the [video](https://youtu.be/wxFzZWqoCng?t=789) referenced in dosdude1's website [macOS Catalina Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/).

Comment: I bougth a second hand macbookpro of 2011 if i remember well. catalina was already installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the menu MacOS Post Install and run the patch "SIP disabler patch" with the GUI menu. The Terminal does not work on my Catalina (macOS 10.15.7).

Comment: How close is [this image](https://i.imgur.com/qqLcl5O.jpg) to menu MacOS Post Install that you are referring to?

Comment: yes that is it!

Answer (score 1):

You get into recovery mode with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>

*Not* <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>

It will enter recovery mode and not just boot into macOS. You can then select Terminal from the "Utilities" menu (if I remember correctly...) and run the command.

When done, reboot the Mac and you should be good to go.

Comment: Also, you need to hold the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> keys down, not press them repeatedly. You can let go of the keys when you see the Apple logo, spinning globe, or other startup screen.

Comment: my mistake, i was hitting repeatedly cmd+R. holding it longly doesnt work on my machine. so i ran csrutil in recovery mode already